# Find int in list with odd count with polars dataframe

Tags: python-polars

I am doing a coding challenge to find the int in a list with an odd value_count.

While I have found a solution, my lack of experience with polars makes me feel that it is verbose.

## Challenge example:

```
input = "[[1,1,2,2,3,3,4],[9,9,8,8,7,7,6]]"

result = find_odd_counts(input)

print(result)
"[4,6]"
```

## The solution I managed to come up with:

```
import polars as pl
from time import perf_counter

data: str
with open('samples.json', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()

t_start = perf_counter()

result = pl.LazyFrame({"arrs": data}).select(pl.col("arrs").str.json_extract(pl.List(pl.List(pl.UInt8))).explode()).with_columns(
    id= pl.int_range(0, pl.col('arrs').count())
).explode("arrs").group_by('id').agg(pl.col('arrs').value_counts(parallel=True)).explode("arrs").unnest('arrs').group_by('id').agg([
    pl.col('arrs').filter(pl.col('counts').mod(2) == 1)
]).explode('arrs').collect().get_column('arrs').to_list()

t_stop = perf_counter()

print(result)
print(f"Compute {round((t_stop-t_start) * 1000, 2)}ms")
```

## Breakdown of the process:

Parse json string:
Note, due to https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8470, I can not use polars.read_json

```
parsed_json = pl.DataFrame({"arrs": data}).select(pl.col("arrs").str.json_extract(pl.List(pl.List(pl.UInt8))).explode())
print(parsed_json)
shape: (500, 1)
┌────────────────┐
│ arrs           │
│ ---            │
│ list[u8]       │
╞════════════════╡
│ [7, 5, … 7]    │
│ [85, 73, … 90] │
│ [81, 86, … 89] │
│ [76, 26, … 96] │
│ …              │
│ [11, 37, … 85] │
│ [13, 51, … 94] │
│ [18, 18, 18]   │
│ [54, 60, … 98] │
└────────────────┘
```

Add ID column:

```
ids = parsed_json.with_columns(
    id= pl.int_range(0, pl.col('arrs').count())
)
print(ids)
shape: (500, 2)
┌────────────────┬─────┐
│ arrs           ┆ id  │
│ ---            ┆ --- │
│ list[u8]       ┆ i64 │
╞════════════════╪═════╡
│ [7, 5, … 7]    ┆ 0   │
│ [85, 73, … 90] ┆ 1   │
│ [81, 86, … 89] ┆ 2   │
│ [76, 26, … 96] ┆ 3   │
│ …              ┆ …   │
│ [11, 37, … 85] ┆ 496 │
│ [13, 51, … 94] ┆ 497 │
│ [18, 18, 18]   ┆ 498 │
│ [54, 60, … 98] ┆ 499 │
└────────────────┴─────┘
```

Count all values:

```
counts = ids.explode("arrs").group_by('id').agg(pl.col('arrs').value_counts(parallel=True)).explode("arrs").unnest('arrs')
print(counts)
shape: (18_157, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬────────┐
│ id  ┆ arrs ┆ counts │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ u8   ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪══════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 48   ┆ 2      │
│ 0   ┆ 42   ┆ 4      │
│ 0   ┆ 84   ┆ 2      │
│ 0   ┆ 67   ┆ 2      │
│ …   ┆ …    ┆ …      │
│ 499 ┆ 24   ┆ 2      │
│ 499 ┆ 56   ┆ 2      │
│ 499 ┆ 60   ┆ 2      │
│ 499 ┆ 54   ┆ 3      │
└─────┴──────┴────────┘
```

Get odd count:

```
find_odds = counts.group_by('id').agg([pl.col('arrs').filter(pl.col('counts').mod(2) == 1)])
print(find_odds)
shape: (500, 2)
┌─────┬──────────┐
│ id  ┆ arrs     │
│ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64 ┆ list[u8] │
╞═════╪══════════╡
│ 0   ┆ [5]      │
│ 1   ┆ [85]     │
│ 2   ┆ [51]     │
│ 3   ┆ [43]     │
│ …   ┆ …        │
│ 496 ┆ [5]      │
│ 497 ┆ [57]     │
│ 498 ┆ [18]     │
│ 499 ┆ [54]     │
└─────┴──────────┘
```

To list:

```
result = find_odds.explode('arrs').get_column('arrs').to_list()
print(result)
[5, 85, 51, ..., 18, 54]
```

[Sample file](https://github.com/bentenjamin/be-ever-in-your-favour/blob/d2c87206bc8b9bb25feb99b8e374d88993d0c375/samples.json)
[Answers](https://github.com/bentenjamin/be-ever-in-your-favour/blob/d2c87206bc8b9bb25feb99b8e374d88993d0c375/answers.json)

This is the only way I could figure out how to apply value_counts over a list of lists, but again it feels like its very sub optimal.

Comment: I don't think the `.read_json()` issue is the same. I get `RuntimeError: BindingsError: "can only deserialize json objects"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main issue is that `.value_counts()` is somewhat awkward to work with.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": ["A", "B", "A", "A"]})

df.select(pl.col("foo").value_counts())
```

```
┌───────────┐
│ foo       │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"A",3}   │
│ {"B",1}   │
└───────────┘
```

Internally, `.value_counts()` runs [`.group_by().count()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.count.html#polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.count)

```py
df.select(df.group_by("foo").count().to_struct("foo"))
```

```
┌───────────┐
│ foo       │
│ ---       │
│ struct[2] │
╞═══════════╡
│ {"A",3}   │
│ {"B",1}   │
└───────────┘
```

i.e. if you group by the actual values, the length of the group is the count.

As you are already using `.group_by`, you can group by the `id` and the value.

- [`.with_row_count()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_row_count.html#polars.DataFrame.with_row_count) can be used to generate an id column.

```py
with open("samples.json") as f:
   df = pl.select(arrs = pl.lit(f.read()).str.json_extract().explode())
   
(df.with_row_count("id")
   .explode("arrs")
   .group_by("id", "arrs", maintain_order=True)
   .count()
)
```

```
shape: (18_157, 3)
┌─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ id  ┆ arrs ┆ count │
│ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ u32 ┆ i64  ┆ u32   │
╞═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 0   ┆ 7    ┆ 2     │
│ 0   ┆ 5    ┆ 3     │
│ 0   ┆ 68   ┆ 2     │
│ 0   ┆ 65   ┆ 4     │
│ …   ┆ …    ┆ …     │
│ 499 ┆ 60   ┆ 2     │
│ 499 ┆ 24   ┆ 2     │
│ 499 ┆ 98   ┆ 2     │
│ 499 ┆ 56   ┆ 2     │
└─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

I've used `maintain_order=True` here but it's not clear if order is important.

From there, you can run your `.filter()` directly.

```py
(df.with_row_count("id")
   .explode("arrs")
   .group_by("id", "arrs", maintain_order=True)
   .count()
   .filter(pl.col("count").mod(2) == 1)
   .select("arrs")
)
```

```
shape: (500, 1)
┌──────┐
│ arrs │
│ ---  │
│ i64  │
╞══════╡
│ 5    │
│ 85   │
│ 51   │
│ 43   │
│ …    │
│ 5    │
│ 57   │
│ 18   │
│ 54   │
└──────┘
```

---

Technically, it is possible to run value counts on list elements with [`.list.eval()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.eval.html#polars.Expr.list.eval)

```py
(df.select(pl.col("arrs").list.eval(pl.element().value_counts()))
   .explode("arrs")
   .filter(pl.col("arrs").struct["counts"].mod(2) == 1)
   .select(arrs = pl.col("arrs").struct[""])
)
```

You can also do the filtering in the List API:

```py
df.select(
   pl.col("arrs") 
     .list.eval(pl.element().value_counts())
     .list.eval(
        pl.element().filter(pl.element().struct["counts"].mod(2) == 1)
          .struct[""]
     )
     .flatten()
)
```

But I think that just adds complexity in this case.

Comment: Wow thank you! This is very elegant and I learnt a lot